# Autoclick Option in select with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to autoselect a product sort filter with jQuery, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work properly.

```
<select class="selectProductSort" id="selectPrductSort1" onchange="">
  <option selected="selected" value="position:asc">Sorter efter</option>
  <option value="price:asc">Pris: laveste først</option>
  <option value="price:desc">Pris: højeste først</option>
  <option value="name:asc">Varenavn: A til Å</option>
  <option value="name:desc">Varenavn: Å til A</option>
  <option value="quantity:desc">Lagervarer først</option>
  <option value="reference:asc">Reference: Laveste først</option>
  <option value="reference:desc">Reference: Højeste først</option>
</select>
```

I've tried the following so far, but no luck.

```
$('.selectProductSort option[value="price:asc"]').prop('selected', 'selected').change();
$('.selectProductSort option[value="price:asc"]').trigger( 'click' );
$('.selectProductSort option[value="price:asc"]').click();
```

I tried with $(document).ready and without.

The first example sets thedesired filter as selected, but the filter function isn't activated, so the products still are ín the same order.

When a filter is selected, the page doesn't reload.

Hope you guys can help me out

https://jsfiddle.net/azc66a0b/

Comment: Is there any error? Please check your browser console for error!

Comment: check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/azc66a0b/ it works!

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT 
I'm running the scripts through Optimizely, since it's a splittest

Comment: if your link or file link contain words such as _advert_, _ad_, _doubleclick_, _click_ and other similar words. Add-blocker will block It.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : set value of select and then call `click()` as shown below. But make sure that your click handler must be registered before calling click.

```
$('.selectProductSort').val("price:asc").click();
```

Check below jsfiddle demos before / after calling click

[JSFIddle with Click handler registered **before** calling click](https://jsfiddle.net/azc66a0b/15/)

[JSFIddle with Click handler registered **after** calling click](https://jsfiddle.net/azc66a0b/16/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
This does the same as the first line of code I tried.
It changes the value in the dropdown, but the function isn't run, so the products still aren't sorted by price

Comment: @plac3bodk, please check my updated answer. Please ensure that your click handler must be registered before calling click as shown in demo links.

Comment: Hi @Bhushan Kawadkar

Thanks for your suggestions. I've tried these, but still doesn't seem to sort the products.
I've checked the dev.console, and I can see that if I manually click the sort by ascending price the following is run

/modules/blocklayered/blocklayered-ajax.php?id_category_layered=66&layered_price_slider=119_575&orderby=price&orderway=asc&_=1452672509889

Do I perhaps need to add the orderby=price&orderway=asc somewhere in the script?

Comment: can you reproduce this on jsfiddle and share the link?

Comment: Hi again @Bhushan Kawadkar

Not really. I'm not sure how to implement that in the script.

I added the form tag to the jsfiddle[link](https://jsfiddle.net/azc66a0b/17/)
I also tried running a submit on the form after setting the val, but it seems to create a loop

Comment: If you are using js library or plugin for sorting, then include it before the `<script>` tag where you are calling click select box script (line of code shown in my answer)

Comment: As mentioned earlier, I'm splittesting on the shop, so I don't have access to any of the source files, which makes it all a bit more complicated.

Comment: I added a link to the shop category where I'm trying to automatically sort by price
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azc66a0b/18/)

Comment: Good! Another problem that a plug-in Chosen with security for autoclick is blocking, an code example use `.val(**value**).change().trigger('chosen:updated')` and dont work `.click()`.

Comment: `$('your select class').val("your value").trigger('click');` this works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#selectPrductSort1').val("name:asc");    // Select by value
    text1 = "Reference: Laveste først";
    $("#selectPrductSort1 option:contains(" + text1 + ")").attr('selected', 'selected'); // select by text
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @user1921115
This also changes the option, but doesn't trigger the actual sort function.
Guess I might have to drop this.